# How to load filtered child collection on child collections with a single database call?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a generic Entity in a C# project, that has a Signals collection.

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid GuidId { get; private set; }
    private readonly List<Signal> signals = new List<Signal>();
    public IEnumerable<Signal> Signals => this.signals.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Each Signal has a collection of Samples.

```
public class Signal
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid GuidId { get; private set; }
    private readonly List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
    public IEnumerable<Sample> Samples => this.samples.AsReadOnly();
}
```

With the Sample entity being

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid GuidId { get; private set; }
    public int SignalId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; private set; }
    public double? Value { get; private set; }
}
```

I want to be able to load the Entity with it's Signals and a filtered subset of Samples. Currently I have the following:

```
/// <param name="guidId">entity id</param>
/// <param name="from">Beginning of the sample period</param>
/// <param name="to">End of the sample period</param>
/// <returns>Populated entity</returns>
public async Task<T> GetByGuidIdWithSignalsAsync(Guid guidId, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var entity = await this.DbContext.Set<T>()
        .Include(s => s.Signals)
        .SingleAsync(s => s.GuidId == guidId);

    foreach (var signal in entity.Signals)
    {
        await this.DbContext.Entry(signal)
            .Collection(s => s.Samples)
            .Query()
            .Where(s => s.TimeStamp >= from && s.TimeStamp <= to)
            .LoadAsync();
    }

    return entity;
}
```

Unfortunately this needs to make multiple calls to the Database for each Signal. Can it be condensed into a single call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ [Query IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter) (free and open source) allows easily filter included entities.

Example:

```
var entity = await this.DbContext.Set<T>()
        .IncludeFilter(s => s.Signals)
        .IncludeFilter(s => s.Signals.SelectMany(x => Samples.Where(sa => sa.TimeStamp >= from && sa.TimeStamp <= to)))
        .SingleAsync(s => s.GuidId == guidId);
```

Comment: Thank Ivan for reporting, the page has been updated (will be available on next reset). EF Core for version 2.x is supported since last month.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, I didn't realise the IncludeFilter was part of the open source library, I'll give a try and comment back on the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something similar to below, it is quite hard to write this without the exact class structure. But it should give you a starting point, happy to help build this further if needed.

```
var entity = await this.DbContext.Set<T>()
        .Include(s => s.Signals)
        .SingleAsync(s => s.GuidId == guidId)
        .SelectMany(entity => entity.Signals
                              .Select(signal => signal.Samples)
                              .Where(sample => sample.TimeStamp >= from && s.TimeStamp <= to);
```

Comment: Excellent, I’ll swap it out after lunch and let you know, 

Comment: Hi @andyb952, it nearly worked ;-) You're query pulled back all of the samples but didn't quite load them into the local cache. The answer below just about manages it in one query...

Answer (score 0):

I think it all will be more easy if you start with the samples. Code would look something like:

```
from row in _db.Samples
where row.Signal.Entity.TimeStamp == whatever
select row
```